# Firebase Messaging in Unity - Getting empty message

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've implemented the Firebase messaging SDK for Unity (only Android atm).
I've been able to receive the push notification with no problem.

The problem I do have, is that the data inside the message is empty.
Here is my C# code:

```
    void Start()
{
    FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += FirebaseMessaging_TokenReceived;
    FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += FirebaseMessaging_MessageReceived;
}

private void FirebaseMessaging_TokenReceived(object sender, TokenReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.Log("FirebasePushNotification - Received Registration Token: " + args.Token);
}

private void FirebaseMessaging_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.Log("FirebasePushNotification - Received a new message!");
    Debug.Log(GetFirebaseMessageString(args.Message));
}

/// <summary>
/// Used for debug
/// </summary>
/// <param name="msg"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private string GetFirebaseMessageString(FirebaseMessage msg)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.AppendLine("############# Firebase Message #############");
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Message Id: ", msg.MessageId));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Message Type: ", msg.MessageType));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Priority: ", msg.Priority));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("From: ", msg.From));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("To: ", msg.To));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Collapse Key: ", msg.CollapseKey));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Error: ", msg.Error));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Error Description: ", msg.ErrorDescription));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Time To Live: ", msg.TimeToLive));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Raw Data: ", msg.RawData));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Notification Opened: ", msg.NotificationOpened));
    if (msg.Notification != null)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format(".Notification Title: ", msg.Notification.Title));
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format(".Notification Tag: ", msg.Notification.Tag));
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format(".Notification Body: ", msg.Notification.Body));
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format(".Notification ClickAction: ", msg.Notification.ClickAction));
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format(".Notification Sound: ", msg.Notification.Sound));
    }
    builder.AppendLine("############# End #############");

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

All the parameters under #### Firebase Message #### are empty.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you may not be sending the message correctly to the FCM backend.  I recommend trying to construct a message in the Firebase Console and sending to your application and if that fails try using the https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/tree/master/messaging/testapp sample.  If you're still running into issues contact our support team https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: did you able to solve this. getting same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems due to C# code.

The String.Format required a brace with the index of parameter that should be inserted on string (indexes start at 0). In your code:

```
string.Format("Message Id: {0}", msg.MessageId)
```

form more info about String.Format look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx

So the fixed code will be:

```
/// <summary>
/// Used for debug
/// </summary>
/// <param name="msg"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private string GetFirebaseMessageString(FirebaseMessage msg)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.AppendLine("############# Firebase Message #############");
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Message Id: {0}", msg.MessageId));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Message Type: {0}", msg.MessageType));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Priority: {0}", msg.Priority));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("From: {0}", msg.From));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("To: {0}", msg.To));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Collapse Key: {0}", msg.CollapseKey));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Error: {0}", msg.Error));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Error Description: {0}", msg.ErrorDescription));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Time To Live: {0}", msg.TimeToLive));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Raw Data: {0}", msg.RawData));
    builder.AppendLine(string.Format("Notification Opened: {0}", msg.NotificationOpened));
    if (msg.Notification != null)
    {
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format(".Notification Title: {0}", msg.Notification.Title));
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format(".Notification Tag: {0}", msg.Notification.Tag));
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format(".Notification Body: {0}", msg.Notification.Body));
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format(".Notification ClickAction: {0}", msg.Notification.ClickAction));
        builder.AppendLine(string.Format(".Notification Sound: {0}", msg.Notification.Sound));
    }
    builder.AppendLine("############# End #############");

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

testing it from Firebase console works.